# What is the correct BING Api POST url for batch url submission, using libcurl?

Tags: c++, json, post, libcurl, bing-api

I am trying to submit a list of urls to BING webmaster. IN CPP

According to BING:

> What is URL Submission API?
> Easy to plug-in API solution that websites can call to notify Bing whenever
> website contents is updated or created allowing instant crawling, indexing
> and discovery of your site content.

I understand that need to send a POST request, JSON request sample:

```
POST /webmaster/api.svc/json/SubmitUrlbatch?​apikey=sampleapikeyEDECC1EA4AE341CC8B6 HTTP/1.1​
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8​
Host: ssl.bing.com​

{
"siteUrl":"http://yoursite.com",​
"urlList":[
"http://yoursite.com/url1",
"http://yoursite.com/url2",
"http://yoursite.com/url3"
]
}
```

I have written the following, using libcurl to send a POST request.

```
std::string curl_post_json(const std::string url, const std::string json) {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string ret;
    struct curl_slist* header = NULL;
    std::string content_len = "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(json.size());
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        header = curl_slist_append(header, content_len.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_response);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ret);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            ret = curl_easy_strerror(res);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return ret;
```

note: write_response is a simple function (pointer) to copy response to string.

I use the following url:

```
https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/api.svc/json/SubmitUrlbatch?apikey=<mykey>
```

but, receive:

```
{"ExceptionType"="System.InvalidOperationException","Message"="Authenticationfailed.","StackTrace"=null**strong text**}
```

What is the proper url for the POST submission?

Comment: You need to generate and use an access token or API key. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingwebmaster/getting-access

Comment: Update: added header=curl_slist_append(header,"Host: ssl.bing.com"); seems to have helped will update again if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the function working now. Needed to add the above.

```
header = curl_slist_append(header,"Host: ssl.bing.com");
```

Also the urlList field must not be empty, if it is empty an error response is returned.